# simple regular expression to eliminate anything after 3 dots

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios4

I am trying to create a simple regular expression that will get rid of anything after three dots in a block of text. Not sure what symbol should I use since the first part will have more than alphabet and number

For example if I pass in

**Anything can go before three dots $ N C >> ... this should be elminated d& < >**

I should get

**Anything can go before three dots $ N C >>**

I have the following

([NOT SURE What goes here])...([ANYTHING HERE]) 
replace with: $1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what you've tried or what RE syntax you are using, so this might not be correct for you but the idea is:

```
^\(.*\)\.\.\..*$
```

Breaking down:

```
^ - start of line
.* - zero or more of anything
\(.*\) - the above tagged
\.\.\. - three dots, escaped to match a literal dot
.*$ - anything else till end of line
```

As I say, your syntax might not be exactly the same as this but the key is you probably need to escape the three dots to make them literal as most RE's use dot as a special character.

Answer (score 1):

The dot stands for any character. An asterisk for 0+ repetitions. So `.*` stands for a (optional) string of any length. To search for dots you have to escape them.

This expression will search for anything followed by 3 dots: `.*\.\.\.`

Adding the optional string at the end: `.*\.\.\..*`

Then you enclose the part you're interested in: `(.*)\.\.\..*` and replace with `$1`. As far as I know, in Cocoa you don't have to escape the brackets, but I'm not 100% sure.

If you're working with lines of text, you might want to add a `^` prefix and `$` suffix to your expression too.

Untested suggestion:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@".*\.\.\..*" options:nil error:&error];
[regex replaceMatchesInString:myString options:nil range:range withTemplate:@"$1"];
```